# Turn off the screen overlay

Tags: overlay, moon-reader

I have installed Moon Reader Pro on my ONYX BOOX MAX 3. Got message while run and setup Moon Reader `The reader needs Storage Permission to manage book files`. After allowing this permission I got another message:

```
Screen overlay detected

To change this permission setting, you first have to turn off the screen overlay from Settings>Apps

Open Settings
```

After opining settings I got list of applications, but there is no Moon Reader in the list.  Without this perdition it is not possible even reed books. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please follow the link to the duplicate Q&A. You have to temporarily close apps/turn off features that use screen overlay, which I believe Moon Reader Pro is not one of them.